# I had a hardtime trying to understand the meaning of this sentence.

Tags: sentence

"When it comes to U.S. shale, it is still very much a case of the only way is up." The first clause was perfectly fine to me, but the second one got me good. Could anyone help me understand the whole sentence in an understandable way? Thank you.

Comment: That is not a grammatical sentence. If you give a more specific reference to exactly where you found it, perhaps someone can deduce from context what the sentence was desired to mean.

Comment: google: 'only way is up' meaning. Kindly consider the English Lang. Learner's site if further help is needed.

Comment: @DavidK It's perfectly grammatical, though it might be clearer to a learner if you bracketed the final clause in quotes: *... it is still a case of 'the only way is up'.*

Comment: @StoneyB I was expecting to find a few extra words, such as "the only way out is up" or "the only way to go is up." An ngrams search comes up with many hits on titles of books, few in the contents; but it seems to have various meanings, such as "I was so low there was nowhere to go but up," or "the only way to succeed in the workplace is to get promoted." I still think it is not possible to deduce the correct meaning of the sentence out of context.

Comment: @DavidK I had no difficulty understanding it; and in any case that's a matter of pragmatics, not grammar. Most of the sentences we get asked about here are ambiguous "out of context": language is not designed to be used without context.

Comment: @StoneyB In context, as we see from the link in the answer below,  it's a quote from a business analyst. And indeed, _in context,_ the meaning is quite clear. _Out of context,_ it can be interpreted differently, as was also demonstrated in the answer section. The main intent of my first remark was a request for context.

Comment: @DavidK The meaning was absolutely clear and obvious to me, even without any more context.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm a Brit of a certain age but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOMvs_1UFCk) is what I immediately thought of

Comment: @JamesRandom Honestly, when I first read it, I thought it had something to do with the method of extracting the resource from the ground, as opposed to resources that can be extracted via horizontal shafts or holes. That is, "it is still the case that the only way is up" because we haven't invented any other ways yet. The idea that it was a business analysis rather than engineering did not occur to me. If I had guessed more astutely, as you did, then I suppose the meaning might have been equally clear to me.

Comment: @DavidK How interesting; a literal interpretation like that would never even have occurred to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase 'the only way is up' is commonly used to mean 'only improvement (or increase) can be expected'. Whatever is being discussed is in a good place and it is surely going to get even better. Reference to the origin of the sentence quoted in the  question makes clear that this is the meaning - the only way for earnings from US shale to go is upwards.

> ... industry analysts point out the U.S. shale boom is perhaps the
>   most notable supply consideration not currently receiving the
>   attention it deserves.

[US shale growth will offset global production problems over the coming months, analysts say](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/08/15/us-shale-growth-will-offset-global-production-problems-over-the-coming.html)

Answer (score 0):

Packages may have text on them indicating which way something should be shipped:

[image: this side up]

It's an instruction to shippers that they should only be carrying it in a single way—otherwise they risk damaging the contents.

In a similar vein, we also hear the phrase:

> The only way is (up/down/left/right/through/forward).

In other words, there is only one way to correctly navigate something.

---

To paraphrase your example sentence:

> When it comes to U.S. shale, it is still very much a case of only being able to handle it in one way.

Further context would be needed to understand *what* can only be done in one way—so, *handle* may not actually be appropriate.

---

**Update**: I see actual content for the question has been provided in another answer. With it, my analysis, while still correct, reaches an odd conclusion.

It's now apparent that it's not talking about only one *way* but only one *result*: given the market, shale prices can only rise.